# What tools are available for value normalization in Rails and Sequel?

Tags: ruby, sequel

I'm using Rails 4 with Sequel for my ORM.  I would like to do some basic normalization on incoming values, such as making casing consistent (`Male` to `male`) and mapping to canonical values (`USA` to `US`).  Where should I be doing this?  Does Sequel provide value normalization hooks?  Or should I be doing it in the Rails controller?

I am currently using the `around_save` Sequel::Model hook, but the Sequel documentation doesn't discuss value normalization so I'm not sure if this is a good place to do it.

```
class People < Sequel::Model
  def before_save
    normalize_gender
    super
  end

  private
  def normalize_gender
    if self.gender.nil?
      self.gender = ''
      return;
    end

    self.gender.downcase!

    self.gender = 'male'   if self.gender == 'm'
    self.gender = 'female' if self.gender == 'f'

    return
  end
end
```

I'm familiar with MVC, but not with Rails and Sequel specifically.  I'm looking for what existing hooks and techniques are available in these tools, not a general discussion of where value normalization should be done.

Comment: There are many answers to this so you're going to generate opinions or broad answers. I'd recommend reading more about MVC and see if it becomes clearer.

Comment: @theTinMan I'm familiar with the MVC model, but I'm not familiar with the specifics of Rails and Sequel.  I'm looking for preferred methods and existing hooks and techniques.  The Sequel documentation doesn't discuss value normalization.  I've edited the question to make it clear I'm not looking for a broad discussion, just what's available in the tools.

Comment: For what's in Sequel, I'd recommend asking on the Sequel IRC or mail-list. The author hangs out there and can answer everything in short order. He's very responsive. He does occasionally drop in here to answer, but if you need information quickly you're better off going to where is. And, at that point, a good thing would be to create an answer to your question summarizing what you found out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use the Sequel input_transformer plugin: http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc-plugins/classes/Sequel/Plugins/InputTransformer.html

Comment: Thanks, that looks useful for generic things like trimming whitespace and normalizing encodings. And hey, Sequel is gorgeous to work with.  Could you comment on doing per-column normalization and my use of `before_save` for that?

Comment: For per column normalization, I would just override the setter method (People#gender=) to do what you want, that's a simpler approach.